# Using SdWebImage and Image Change immediately by swift

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, sdwebimage

[This is Question Video](https://youtu.be/-gCj_KVbIjI)

I have a problem about imageView by using SDWebImage.
I change user's image and already get new user's image url, but when I push to this ViewController, it will show the old image first and change to new image.
What's wrong with me?
Thanks.

```
var avatar:String = "" // previous VC data pass to here 

var photoImageView:UIImageView = { () -> UIImageView in
    let ui = GeneratorImageView()
    ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
    ui.layer.masksToBounds = true 
    ui.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
    return ui
}()

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    iconImageFromUrl(imageView: iconImageView, url: avatar, isResize: false)
}    


func iconImageFromUrl(imageView:UIImageView, url:String,isResize:Bool) {

imageView.setShowActivityIndicator(true)
imageView.setIndicatorStyle(.gray)

imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url), placeholderImage: nil, options: .lowPriority, progress: nil
    , completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in

        guard image != nil else{
            imageView.image = resizeImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultIcon"), newWidth: 50)
            return
        }

        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) //make sure your image in this url does exist, otherwise unwrap in a if let check / try-catch

            if data != nil
            {
                if let image = UIImage(data: data!)
                {
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {

                        if isResize == true{
                            imageView.image = resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 250)
                        }else{
                            imageView.image = image
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
})
}
```

Answer (score 4):

`sd_setImage` method is written inside a category of `UIImageView`. After downloading the image it sets the image on `UIImageview` on its own and in the completion closure returns the downloaded/cached `UIImage` as well.

You dont need to create Data from `imageUrl` and set it again. If you want to resize image, you can do it on the returned image.

Also, you dont need to check the image nil for setting the default image, just pass the resized default image as placeholder image

```
imageView.sd_setImage(with: URL(string:url), placeholderImage: resizeImage(image: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "defaultIcon"), newWidth: 50), options: .lowPriority, progress: nil
, completed: { (image, error, cacheType, url) in
    guard image != nil else {
        return
    }

    if isResize {
          imageView.image = resizeImage(image: image, newWidth: 250)
    } })
```

Comment: because I call the async api to get the imageUrl , it will happen the view show up and the image doesn't change.

Comment: @Beginnerrrrrr: Yes you are correct. The problem here is the resizeImage after everytime image is loaded from cache/memory by SDWebImageCache. You can choose to not show any image till then, but this will not solve the issue of resizing image every time. If you want, you can save the resized image in SDWebImageCache, by appending width as query parameter in the image URL.